# Why asp.net MVC5 search method return huge url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to implement a search method, this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string SearchBy, string SearchString)
{
    var customers = db.Customers.Include(c => c.ContractType).Include(c => c.City).Include(c => c.County);
    switch (SearchBy)
    {
        case "CustomerName":
        {
            return View(customers.Where(c => c.CustomerName.Contains(SearchString)).ToList()); 
        }
        case "City":
        {
            return View(customers.Where(c => c.City.CityName.Contains(SearchString)).ToList());
        }
        case "County":
        {
            return View(customers.Where(c => c.County.CountyName.Contains(SearchString)).ToList());
        }
        case "StreetAndNumber":
        {
            return View(customers.Where(c => c.StreetAndNumber.Contains(SearchString)).ToList());
        }
        default:
        {
            return View(customers.ToList());   
        }    
    }
}
```

This is the view code for search:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Customers",FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("SearchBy", new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text="Customer Name", Value="CustomerName", Selected=true },
            new SelectListItem {Text="City", Value="City" },
            new SelectListItem {Text="County", Value="County"},
            new SelectListItem {Text="StreetAndNumber", Value="StreetAndNumber"}
        })
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

When I run this view and try to search something I get this URL:

Requested URL:    http://localhost:50822/Customers?SearchBy=CustomerName&SearchString=el**&DXScript=1_225%2C1_164%2C1_130%2C1_127%2C1_202%2C1_213%2C1_207%2C1_210%2C1_129%2C17_36%2C17_3%2C1_206%2C1_218%2C1_146%2C17_8%2C1_208%2C1_148%2C1_147%2C17_9%2C1_162%2C1_170%2C1_223%2C1_189%2C1_191%2C1_224%2C1_174%2C17_10%2C1_217%2C1_216%2C1_201%2C17_35%2 ....**

I do not know from where is coming the bold part of the URL, and is very very long !!!

Con some one tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using DevExpress components by any chance?

Comment: yes, I do use Devexpress

Comment: Right. Well that's where the `DXScript=` parameter is coming from... See https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q402665 for example.

Comment: What Can I do to not get this DXScript?, on this view I have no DevExpress control.

Comment: I'm afraid without any experience of the DevExpress controls, I can't help you - but I strongly recommend that you add the details of which DevExpress products you're using (and how) to the question.

Comment: One option would be to add a `[HttpPost]public ActionResult Index(string SearchBy, string SearchString) { return RedirectToAction("Index", new { SearchBy = SearchBy, SearchString  = SearchString }); }` and change the form to `FormMethod.Post`

Comment: Thank you, your feedback was very useful. I have no Devexpress Controls in my project, but I have all DevExpress references, because I was planning to ad some controls. I made a new project to test the Search method without any DevExpress reference and I got no more issues, method is running OK.

Comment: Apparently its by design when using DevExpress with a GET as discussed [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T249664)

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two answers the DevExpress support team has suggested for this, each with their own drawbacks.

The first is to manually remove the DXScript hidden input from the form via JS. It would look like this:

```
document.querySelector('input[name="DXScript"]').remove();
```

The drawback being that DXScript is used by devexpress to tell it which scripts and CSS to load, and it could cause problems.

The second solution is to change the form GET to a form POST. In the code above you would just change `FormMethod.Get` to `FormMethod.Post`. The drawbacks of this approach are that if you have other query params that determine content on the page, they will no longer be in the URL if you desire to have the user be able to copy-paste or bookmark to go back to that exact page.